# Adding Text in Header for Specific Pages

Tags: header-footer

I am preparing some class notes and I want to add the "session number" and "date of session" at the header of specific pages manually. I also want the "page number" on all pages. I am using the article document class.

For example, at page 1 header I want to have

**Session 1, 19.Feb.2017**

and at page 3 header I want to have

**Session 2, 21.Feb.2017**

How should I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\textbf{Session No. Date}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-8]

\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although you did not post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), here's a suggestion in combination with `article`: You should have a look at the `fancyhdr` package. There are tons of tutorials out there how to get headers (even only for one page).

Comment: @TeXnician: Sorry I am new LaTex! :) I searched before asking the question but I couldn't find anything that matches my need. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using `fancyhdr` and own pagestyles for this special task. This is based on your first MWE.

I've just defined a new pagestyle via `\fancypagestyle` which has only one change (the rest is kept from the overall setup): it sets one head (`\lhead`) to a temporary value (saved in `\tmpx`). For your convenience (to not write `\renewcommand{\tmpx}{}` every time) I introduced a setter-macro called `\tmp`, which you have to call to set the information used in the new pagestyle.

The usage is simple: On the page you want extra information on you just set them using `\tmp` and then load the other pagestyle using `\thispagestyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{sec}{\lhead{\tmpx}}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}\tmp{Session 1 -- Date}\thispagestyle{sec}
\lipsum[1-20]

\newpage

\section{Second Section}\tmp{Session 2 -- Date}\thispagestyle{sec}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1). Thanks. Can you explain what you have done? I mean what are those `\tmpx` and `\tmp`? :) I also changed the MWE in the question a little. :)

Comment: @H.R. I've updated the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\markright` (and disable `\sectionmark`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{Session \rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\newcommand{\session}[2]{% #1 = title, #2 = date
  \clearpage
  \section{#1}
  \markright{\thesection, #2}
}

\begin{document}

\session{First Section}{19 Feb.\ 2017}
\lipsum[1-8]

\session{Second Section}{21 Feb.\ 2017}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. :) Does this solution work even if the sections are not at the beginning of a page? I also want the session date to appear once. :)

Comment: @H.R. Remove `\clearpage` from the definition. Where do you want the session date to appear “once”?

Comment: I want it to appear just at the first page where the new session begins.

Comment: @H.R. Not clear, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your time. The answer of TeXnician solved my problem. :)